# Select only needed object property from array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

How to do this in a more elegant way?

```
output = []
results.each do |res|
  output.push res['text']
end
```

Comment: give a small sample for results array, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) method:

```
output = results.map { |res| res['text'] }
```